# how to map one csv file content to second csv file and write it another csv using unix

Tags: shell, unix, csv

After writing some unix scripts I am able to manage to get data from different xml files to csv format and now I got stuck with the following problem

file1.csv : contains

```
1,5,6,7,8
2,3,4,5,9
1,6,10,11,12
1,5,11,12
```

file2.csv : contains

```
1,Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through,Franky,Sam,Sumo
2,Franky
3,Sam
4,Sumo
5,Mango,Tuna,Webby
6,Tuna,Webby,Through
7,Through,Sam,Sumo
8,Nothing
9,Sam,Sumo
10,Sumo,Mango,Tuna
11,Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through
12,Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through,Franky
```

output I want is

```
1,5,6,7,8
Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through,Franky,Sam,Sumo
Mango,Tuna,Webby
Tuna,Webby,Through
Through,Sam,Sumo
Nothing
Common word:None

2,3,4,5,9
Franky
Sam
Sumo
Mango,Tuna,Webby
Sam, Sumo
Common Word:None

1,6,10,11,12
Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through,Franky,Sam,Sumo
Tuna,Webby,Through
Sumo,Mango,Tuna
Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through
Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through,Franky
Common word: Tuna

1,5,11,12
Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through,Franky,Sam,Sumo
Mango,Tuna,Webby
Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through
Mango,Tuna,Webby,Through,Franky
Common word: Mango,Tuna,Webby
```

I apprecaite any help.

Thanks

I got some solution but not complete

```sh
##!/bin/bash
count=1
count_2=1
for i in `cat file1.csv`
do
    echo $i > $count.txt
    cat $count.txt | tr "," "\n" > $count_2.txt
    count=`expr $count + 1`
    count_2=`expr $count_2 + 1`
done;
#this code will create separte files for each line in file1.csv,
bash file3_search.sh
##########################

file3_search.sh
================
##!/bin/bash
cat file2.csv | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/[ ]*$//' > trim.txt
dos2unix -q 1.txt 1.txt
dos2unix 2.txt 2.txt
dos2unix 3.txt 3.txt
echo "1st Combination results"
for i in `cat 1.txt`
do
cat trim.txt | egrep -w $i
done > Combination1.txt;
echo "2nd Combination results"
for i in `cat 2.txt`
do
    cat trim.txt | egrep -w $i
done > Combination2.txt;
echo "3rd Combination results"
for i in `cat 3.txt`
do
    cat trim.txt | egrep -w $i
done > Combination3.txt;
```

Guys I am not good at programming (I am software tester) please someone can re-factor my code and also please tell me how to get the common word in those Combination.txt file

Comment: I have posted my script (homework) please help me how to get the common word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it works:

```sh
for line in $(cat 1.csv) ; do 
    echo $line ; 
    grepline=`echo $line | sed 's/ \+//g;s/,/,|/g;s/^\(.*\)$/^(\1,)/'`; 
    egrep $grepline 2.csv
    egrep $grepline 2.csv | \
    awk -F "," '
      { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
          {s[$i]+=1} 
      }
      END { for (key in s) 
              {if (s[key]==NR) { tp+=key "," } 
              } 
            if (tp!="") {print "Common word(s): " gensub(/,$/,"","g",tp)} 
              else {print "Common word: None"}}'
   echo
done
```

HTH

Comment: hi thanks for the help but if my file contains more than one common word it returns only one word how to get all the common words I am trying to work on it if i can solve I will post it, if you know easy way please comment. I have changed the output file have look. Thanks

Comment: Actually you should at least resolve this as this is your homework. But I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for you. It depends on associative array capabilities of bash version 4:

```
IFS=,
declare -a words

# read and store the words in file2
while read line; do
    set -- $line
    n=$1
    shift
    words[$n]="$*"
done < file2.csv

# read file1 and process
while read line; do
    echo "$line"

    set -- $line
    indexes=( "$@" )
    NF=${#indexes[@]}
    declare -A common

    for (( i=0; i<$NF; i++)); do
        echo "${words[${indexes[$i]}]}"

        set -- ${words[${indexes[$i]}]}
        for word; do
            common[$word]=$(( ${common[$word]} + 1))
        done
    done

    printf "Common words: "
    n=0
    for word in "${!common[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${common[$word]} -eq $NF ]]; then
            printf "%s " $word
            (( n++ ))
        fi
    done
    [[ $n -eq 0 ]] && printf "None"

    unset common
    printf "\n\n"
done < file1.csv
```